# Starting a Vaadin project with maven failing

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to get vaadin installed, and starting the tutorial that I find on: 
https://vaadin.com/maven
But I'm getting the error below, when I run the mvn command.

I typically prefer downloading the jars manually and linking them to my project in eclipse, without relying on public repositories. I saw other questions and answers that pointed to https://vaadin.com/download but that link now re-route to https://vaadin.com/framework/get-started

Any ideas how to get started ?

```
c:\vaadin\mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=7.6.6 -DgroupId=org.test -DartifactId=vaadin-app -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2
.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.p
lugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.ap
ache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plug
in-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven
.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for or
g.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin
-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.
plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.
apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3
.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.pl
ugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apac
he.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin
-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.
plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.
apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-asse
mbly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apac
he.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact d
escriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependenc
y-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.ma
ven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-pl
ugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.mav
en.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor fo
r org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.
org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.16.215] failed: Connection timed out: connec
t
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/mav
en2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.16.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cache
d in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are
 forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://rep
o.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.16.215] failed: Connection ti
med out: connect
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in th
e local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache
.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.16.215] failed: Connection timed out: conne
ct
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-17T08:33:42+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org
.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\cgereige\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache
.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: You should try to get the download working. What happens when you enter the URL in the browser? e.g. [click](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom)

Comment: opening the url (say: -1.3.pom) in browser opens the pom file

Comment: Do you use an HTTP proxy that is not configured with maven?

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: @HenriKerola Apache Maven 3.3.9

Comment: @Charbel Thanks it's latest so no problem there.. then you should check your proxy configuration for Maven. It's failing to download standard maven plugins..

Comment: @SteffenHarbich yes there are HTTP proxy, I used that in the settings.xml of maven

Comment: ok turn out to be a proxy issue! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this command (given in one line):

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application \
-DarchetypeVersion=7.x.x \
-DgroupId=your.company \
-DartifactId=project-name \
-Dversion=0.1 \
-Dpackaging=war
```

Extracted from [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/getting-started/getting-started-maven.html).

Comment: So `-Dpackaging=war` is the only difference?